# How to select neighbourgs p elements without selecting all p elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Given a dom such :

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<h2>Title</h2>   <-- click this
<p>Text</p>       <-- toogle this
<p>Text</p>       <-- and this
<p>Text</p>       <-- and this. ONLY.
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
```

**How to toggle the `p` elements directly under a `h2` title and not the other `p` elements ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that you are missing the `/` at the end of each `<p>` should be `<p>Text</p>`

You can use `.nextUntil("h2")`

Like this:

```
$("h2").click(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil("h2").toggle();
});
```

**Working demo**

```js
$("h2").click(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil("h2").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
```